# full screen responsive navbar, image and text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive-design

I am very new to Front end dev, this is my first client project and i need some help with it please.

How can I make everything responsive to mobile and tablet devices please

Here's the code:

```
const Header = () => {
    return(
        <div className="cont fw9 f3 ">
            <div className=" topbar">
             <img className="top-logo grow" src={logo} alt="logo" />
                <Navbar  expand="sm" className="list ">
                     <Nav.Link  href="#home"> Home </Nav.Link>
                     <Nav.Link  href="#features">About Us</Nav.Link>
                     <Nav.Link  href="#pricing">Services</Nav.Link>
                     <Nav.Link  href="#tt">Our Team</Nav.Link>
                     <Nav.Link  href="#tt">Sustainability</Nav.Link>
                     <Nav.Link  href="#rr">Become an investor</Nav.Link>
                     <Nav.Link  href="#dd">Contact</Nav.Link>                  
                </Navbar> 
            </div>
              <div className=" header-main" >
                <p className="header-title b dark-blue"> INTEGRATED COLD CHAIN</p>
                <p className="header-sec f5  i black b "> Ifria is an Integrated Cold Chain Company in North and West African markets. Ifria’s mission is to develop new, modern and efficient perishable product storage capacities that can more efficiently serve the growing and rapidly changing needs of the Panafrican markets. </p>
              </div>
        </div>
```

this is the css:

```
.cont {
  animation: animate 15s  infinite;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@keyframes animate{
  0%,100%{
    background-image: url(../Images/bg.png);
  }
  25%{
    background-image: url(../Images/bg2.png);
  }
  50%{
    background-image: url(../Images/bg3.png);
  }
}

.topbar{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 130px;

}

.list{
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.top-logo{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  left: 90px;
}

 .nav-link{
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black !important;
  }
  .nav-link:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1); 

}

.header-main{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  top: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header-title{
    font-size: 45px;
}

.header-sec{

}
```

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong or just point me to the right article to read more about responsive website. I tried watching a lot of yt vids but didnt really help

Comment: Use bootstrap, bluma or any of the exisiting framewarks to build it faster, so far what i see is HTML & css only that will be a tideous and really long first client project..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options for ensuring responsive web designing. I will list some of the options which can be used according to your project's need and requirement :

**Bootstrap :**
Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing responsive, mobile-first websites.Bootstrap is completely free to download and use .
But the problem with bootstrap is its bundle size. If you are looking for way to load you application faster, inclusion of bootstrap can increase the initial load time . It will take around **60.9kB** extra to your application bundle when minified .
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/

**Zurb foundation :**
Similar to bootstrap , with a decent developer community and has most of the features provided by bootstrap . The main advantage is its size . Comparing to 60.9kb size of bootstrap , zurb foundation will take only **181bytes** when minified. As foundation is not that popular compared to bootstrap , it is not used widely . But i have tried it and serves maximum of responsive issues.
https://get.foundation/sites/getting-started.html

The above ones are front end frameworks for responsive design. But i would personally recommend you to try our the features provided by css itself which will help in reducing the application's size and improved performance. You could use a mix of below items to create stunning UI (use it according to your context) :

1. CSS FLEXBOX
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp
2. CSS GRID
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
3. CSS Media query
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
   https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

**Also some of good reference links to know the difference and use it wisely :**

- https://web.dev/responsive-web-design-basics/
- https://css-tricks.com/quick-whats-the-difference-between-flexbox-and-grid/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_responsive.htm

Some video tutorials :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=705XCEruZFs
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68O6eOGAGqA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJSoEo8JSnc

Always look for the perfect solution rather than the easiest solution as the solution we are using now helps in the long run when the project gets bigger . All the best .

Comment: Thank you so much man, i appreciate the help a lot